Snowflake Native app with container service, grant imported privilege on Snowflake DB
How can a snowflake native application built with container services request or grant imported privilege on Snowflake DB?
According to Snowflake Documentation, the grant can only be added through SQL commands. Once I create the application, and run the below SQL, It shows the error
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE SNOWFLAKE TO APPLICATION my_app;

-- Error
Privilege 'IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON SNOWFLAKE DB' cannot be granted because it is not requested by current application version

Sharing the manifest.yml for reference:
manifest_version: 1

version:
  name: v1_9
  label: "v1_9"
  comment: "My Application"

artifacts:
  setup_script: setup.sql
  readme: readme.md
  container_services:
    images:
      - /insta_spcs_db/app_schema/repo_stage/iqr_app_image
  default_web_endpoint:
     service: core.iqr_service
     endpoint: iq

configuration:
  log_level: debug
  trace_level: always
  grant_callback: app_public.grant_callback

lifecycle_callbacks:
  version_initializer: app_public.version_init

privileges:
  - CREATE COMPUTE POOL:
      description: "Enable application to create its own compute pool(s)"
  - BIND SERVICE ENDPOINT:
      description: "Enables application to expose service endpoints"
  - CREATE WAREHOUSE:
      description: "Enables application to create its own WAREHOUSE"


references:
  - snowflake_query_history:
      label: "Snowflake Query History"
      description: "A database in the consumer account that exists outside the APPLICATION object."
      privileges:
        - SELECT
      object_type: VIEW
      multi_valued: false
      register_callback: app_public.register_single_reference


The solution is to add "IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON SNOWFLAKE DB" privilege in the manifest file.
privileges:
  - CREATE COMPUTE POOL:
      description: "Enable application to create its own compute pool(s)"
  - BIND SERVICE ENDPOINT:
      description: "Enables application to expose service endpoints"
  - CREATE WAREHOUSE:
      description: "Enables application to create its own WAREHOUSE"
  - IMPORTED PRIVILEGES ON SNOWFLAKE DB:
      description: "Enables application to import privileges on snowflake DB"

